# Dynamically building a table outside of Activity class

Tags: java, android

I have used the following code to pass an activity via the constructor into a non activity class where I plan to dynamically build a table.

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass(this);

public class MyClass {
    public Activity activity;

    public MyClass(Activity _activity){
        this.activity = _activity;
    }
}​
```

This code seems to work but the following code is unable to resolve the symbols for setId, setBackgroundColor, Color, and setLayoutParams.  How do I use this to build my table in my class and resolve the symbols in question?

```
TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
tr_head.setId(10);
tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));​
```

Comment: What's the error? And what is `this` in `new TableRow(this)`?

Comment: seems android. Add android tag

Comment: this is activity and the first error is unable to resolve symbol 'setId'.

Comment: Do I need to pass the View in to be able to access the TableRow?

Answer (score 0):

setId() expects resource of type Id. It won't work with an integer value. More details about resources of type 'id' can be found at the following link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

I created a test class

```
public class TestClass {

public void test(Activity activity) {
    TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(activity);
    tr_head.setId(R.id.inputString); //Add an id here
    tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    tr_head.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    activity.setContentView(tr_head);

}}
```

And then in my activity's onCreate, I called

```
new TestClass().test(this);
```

Comment: This works if I run the code in the Activity class under oncreate() but, not when I try to run the code in my new class.

Comment: Are you doing all the necessary imports in your class ?

Comment: All the imports for the activity class are in my new class.  It just doesn't allow me to access the TableLayout even though TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(activity); does work.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is I am not having success accessing the UI outside of the activity class even though I pass the activity into my class via the constructor.

Comment: I created a class, created a method, passed an 'activity' to this method and copied your code. Didn't see any errors. And you should be able to invoke 'setContentView' on this 'activity' variable and pass this table.

Comment: Great, is this how I invoke 'setContentView'  setContentView(activity)? I guess I am asking where in my class code do I invoke 'setContentView'?

Comment: it would be activity.setContentView

Comment: Could you show me in your code snippet how you used 'setContentView' in your class?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `setContentView` is a method of `Activity`, activities are responsible for displaying UI, after all